# Why is "git add" adding "C:/Program Files/Git/" in front of a given path starting with "/"?

Tags: git, path, git-bash, git-add

While I am trying to do `git add` for a folder or for all files, I am getting the fatal error as shown below.

```
MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/d95x-dev (master)
$ git add /vendor
fatal: C:/Program Files/Git/vendor: 'C:/Program Files/Git/vendor' is outside repository at 'C:/xampp/htdocs/d95x-dev'
```

It is automatically adding this path `C:/Program Files/Git/` in front of the folder name that I am trying to add.

Why is it doing this?

My folder is at the path `C:/xampp/htdocs/d95x-dev`, how can I tell `git add` to add `C:/xampp/htdocs/d95x-dev/vendor` instead?

Comment: You meant `vendor` or `vendor/` or `./vendor`, not `/vendor`.

Comment: @mk yes, Thanks it should be vendor or vendor/ but my main issue here is that, the path C:/Program Files/Git/  is getting added to the folder name for some reason

Comment: @mk yes, Thanks again, actually after adding it by writing the `git add vendor` it the way you said it also helped with that issue of path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
git add vendor/
```

Or, You can also add all the files using

```
git add .
```